# How to edit OndemandGrid and update to the JSONRest Store

Tags: model-view-controller, dojo, dgrid, jsonreststore

The JsonRest store I created is shown below

```
var questionBaseURL = "/" + contextName + "/service/questions/" + projectId + "/";
var questionStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({
    target: questionBaseURL,
    handleAs: 'json',
    idProperty: 'questionId'
});

questionStore = new dojo.store.Observable(questionStore);
var memoryStore = new dojo.store.Memory();
var questionCacheStore = new dojo.store.Cache(questionStore, memoryStore);
```

Which I use to render into the Grid created as below

```
var CustomGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection]);
var questionGrid = new CustomGrid({
    store: questionCacheStore,
    columns: [
        editor({
            label: "Questions",
            field: "question",
            editor: "text",
            editOn: "dblclick",
            sortable: true,
            autoSave:true
        })
    ],
    selectionMode: "single",
    cellNavigation: false
}, "questions");
questionGrid.startup();
questionGrid.renderArray(questionArray);
```

The data is properly populated in the grid. Now, since am using "editor", I am able edit the populated data in the grid. I am not sure how exactly to detect if the data has been edited (dirty data ) and which method to call to carry the updated data back to the server. I couldn't find any easy documentation. So any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid's `save` method to push all items with dirty data back to the server.  There is also a `revert` method which can be called to discard any dirty data.  These are listed in the [OnDemandList and OnDemandGrid documentation](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid).

These methods are defined in `dgrid/_StoreMixin` which is inherited by `OnDemandList` (and `OnDemandGrid`).  The `editor` column plugin calls `updateDirty` (also defined by `_StoreMixin`) when changes are made, which updates a `dirty` hash.  `save` will check this hash and call `put` on the store for each dirty item.

Comment: I have had the same idea while implementing it. But As i double click the row and perform any edit operation, locally the row grid gets changed and a POST request is being fired. As you can see i am using Observable Store and Cache store. I am able to get the old data and new data of the row by using the event "questionGrid.on("dgrid-datachange", function(evt){});". I tried calling the save method of both stores inside the event but it logs an error as "Object [object Object] has no method 'save'". Where shall i call this method ? could you please  be more detailed ?

Comment: `save` is a method on the grid, not on the store.  However, I missed that your `editor` column has `autoSave: true`, which will cause the grid's `save` function to be called each time an editor field is changed anyway.  However, I'd normally expect that to fire a PUT through JsonRest, not a POST...